# sequelize Mysql data two between date all record show but some ... findall REST API ......simple problems

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

This my API Code .it work perfectly but missing my  "startedDate":"2022-01-01", and
"endDate":"2022-01-31" … how I write the the function  pls solved my problem and share your idea..

```
  async getcurrentmonthorder2(req, res, next) {
        try {
    
            const {startedDate ,endDate} = req.body;
            
            db.product.findAll({
                attributes:[[sequelize.fn('sum',sequelize.col('profit_total')),'total']],
             
                where : {"createdAt" : {[Op.between] : [new Date(startedDate).setHours(0,0,0,0) , new Date(endDate).setHours(23,59,59,999) ]}},
               
             
            })
    
        
          
       
            .then(list => {
                res.status(200).json({ 'success': true, data: list });
               
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                next(err)
            });
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ 'errors': "" + err });
    }

}
```

#I have got output from postman..

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "total": "121",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

#but I want to  this output pls help share your idea

```
 {
        "success": true,
        "data": [
            {
                "total": "121",
                "startedDate":"2022-01-01",
                "endDate":"2022-01-31"
            }
        ]
    }
```

my data

```
{id: 1, total: 20, profit_total: 15, createdAt: "2021-12-30T15:59:10.000Z",…}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the **attributes** which you indicated in your query: You told SEQUELIZE to return only **TOTAL**. I suggest you this::

```
db.product.findAll({
   attributes:[[sequelize.fn('sum',sequelize.col('profit_total')),'total'], 'startedDate', 'endDate'],
   where : {
     "createdAt" : {
        [Op.between] : [new Date(startedDate).setHours(0,0,0,0), new Date(endDate).setHours(23,59,59,999) ]}
   },
})
```

Comment: it works for me, I forgot to remove the **[]** on ``'startedDate' and 'endDate'`. I updated my solution. Thank you